# How to find the number of characters in a string in java

Tags: java

Below code outputs only "Enter a string" and accepts user input however, does not display the number of characters in the string. Kindly help!

```
System.out.println("Enter a string");
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String result = scan.nextLine();


try {
 while (a != null) {
  count++;
 }
} catch (Exception e) {
 System.out.println("Invalid string");
}

System.out.println("The number of characters are : " + count);
```

Comment: Please spell out what exactly you expect your program to do step by step.

Comment: You have a pretty obvious infinite loop there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String.length()` to calculate the length of your input string:

```
    System.out.println("Enter a string");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    String a = scan.nextLine();

    System.out.println("The number of characters are : " + a.length());
```

Answer (score 0):

oschlueter is right. Also, when using `java.util.Scanner` to get a string from user input, you won't need a try/catch to look for invalid strings, as anything the user can input can be a String. However, you will need a Try/Catch when asking for a number through `Scanner.nextInt`.

Also, it's generally recommended to catch a specific error and not just `Exception`. In this case, you would catch `java.util.InputMismatchException`.